# Adding none-printing text in Google Docs?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I have a Google Docs document and am keen to add a line of text (perhaps in the header or footer) just to serve as a reminder for myself... but I don't want it to be visible when printing or exporting as a PDF.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is Google Write? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Google Docs I meant :) I was thinking 'Write' was the more specific term for the word processor app but it seems I was wrong!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's not possible. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].